# Using shell commands containing "," in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, celery

I'm trying to run celery using docker-compose and would like to execute the following command using docker-compose.

`celery worker --app=worker.app --pool=gevent --queues=queue1,queue2  --concurrency=20 -- loglevel=INFO`

Traditionally, i would do something like this

`[celery, worker, --app=worker.app, --pool=gevent, --concurrency=20, --queues=queue1,  --loglevel=INFO]`

How do i incorporate the "," that i use to separate two queue names while using this format?

I tried

```
command: >
      /bin/sh -c "celery worker --app=worker.app --pool=gevent --queues=queue1,queue2  --concurrency=20 --loglevel=INFO"
```

but ended up getting a exited with code 64 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the YAML block list format, or put individual words in quotes.

```yaml
option1:
  command:
    - celery
    - worker
    - --queues=queue1,queue2
    - ...
option2:
  command: [celery, worker, '--queues=queue1,queue2', ...]
```

You can also consider specifying this in the Dockerfile that builds your image.  (In general I consider it preferable to specify `CMD` in a Dockerfile if you can; for Celery workers in particular it's common for your Celery container to use the same image as your main Django/Flask app, except for the command, so for this specific case putting `command:` in `docker-compose.yml` makes sense.)  If you do this, Docker will wrap a bare command in `sh -c` so you shouldn't need special YAML escaping, or if you specify individual words in the command, it must be a valid quoted JSON array.

```
CMD celery worker --queues=queue1,queue2 ...
CMD ["celery", "worker", "--queues=queue1,queue2", "..."]
```